# Identity Server 4 - REST API request to authenticate user

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4

I am currently diving into `Identity Server 4` and working on a local project for my own learning.

I currently have a login page located within the `Identity Server 4` project which allows the user to login, this works perfectly fine.

The question I have is, can I make a `REST API` request passing in username and password to authenticate the user instead of using the login page located within the Identity Server project? this may sound a very simple question for some, but my knowledge on this is very limited at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about [Resource owner password flow](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html).
It allows you to request access token with username/password pair.
After that you can use access token in a usual way to access your API.
Link above says that

> The spec recommends using the resource owner password grant only for “trusted” (or legacy) applications.

Comment: Worth reading this if going down this route too: https://www.scottbrady91.com/oauth/why-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-type-is-not-authentication-nor-suitable-for-modern-applications